# Can I set Spring AOP pointcut on mybatis mapper?

Tags: spring, interface, mybatis, spring-aop, mapper

```
<aop:pointcut id="logPointcut" expression="(execution(* net.com..a..*Controller.*(..))
                                         or execution(* net.com.a..*ServiceImpl.*(..))
                                         or execution(* net.com.a..*Mapper.*(..)) />
```

It is pointcut setting in xml file

```
public interface UserMapper {
    List<UserVO> selectUser(UserVO userVO) throws Exception;
}
```

I want to set AOP pointcut in interface.
They're created by mybatis.

The expression above does not apply to the mapper.

Is it fundamentally impossible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has been asked dozens of times here, and always by people who want to use Spring AOP, but never really bothered to look into its documentation or at least search StackOverflow before posting questions. How can you survive as a developer like this?

The short answer is:

- No, Spring AOP can only intercept methods of Spring components.
- If you want to intercept non-Spring stuff, use AspectJ. You can use it with or without Spring. If you want to use it from Spring, the Spring manual tells you how to configure it. Otherwise the AspectJ manual tells you.

Comment: First of all thank your clearness answer. But I have a question when read your answer, 
`<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="mapperLocations" value="classpath:mapper/**/*Mapper.xml"></property>
    </bean>
 <bean id="sqlSession" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate">
   <constructor-arg index="0" ref="sqlSessionFactory" />
 </bean>`
I think that It is syntax for registering as a spring bean in xml. Isn't it??

Comment: I do not know, I am not a Spring user, just an AOP expert.

Comment: Thank you for your fast feedback.

Comment: And thank you for accepting my not particularly friendly answer (sorry!) without complaints. Not many people can accept criticism like you did. But because you can, you will have a steep learning curve. Good luck!